# How to go about utilizing acorn.js in another .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a Javascript translator using a Javascript parser called "acorn.js." I'm writing my code in Sublime using a Node build system. Calling the following line:

```
require("./acorn.js");
```

produces no errors, but whenever I attempt to access any functions within that file, an undefined error is thrown. Is there any way I can import or reference this library to gain access to its functions without having to utilize a JQuery import or something of the like?

**Here is the answer:**

```
var test = acorn.parse("var x;");
```

And if you're using this specific library, what is returned is an AST of the contents of what you parse. In this case, it's the string "var x;".

Comment: please post the exact code you use to access the functions from the module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the imported module to a variable. For ex :

```
var acorn = require("./acorn.js");
```

And access the methods from that variable :

```
acorn.parse(in,out);
```